# Tuple TypeError when assigning Value to Cell in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm a first time user of openpyxl and am struggling with basic Cell editing.
In the following code I'm trying to change the Cell Value "B3" in my Excel File to a String Value (eg. "Germany").

What I don't seem to understand is why the openpyxl Worksheet & Worbook are an immutable tuple type and [the Documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#create-a-workbook) is suggesting the simple Cell Assignment I'm using.

Here's my Code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook


# 1. Open Excel File
wb = Workbook()
wb = load_workbook(filename="myFile.xlsm", read_only=True, keep_vba=True, data_only=True)
ws = wb.active[1]  # ws is the second Worksheet in the Workbook

# 2. Enter Input (Country)

ws["B3"] = "Germany"

wb.save("myFile.xlsm")
```

> ws["B3"] = "Germany"
> TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment

**Expectation**
I expected to find a Excel file that contains my assigned value in the given cell.

I appreciate every answer - thanks!

Comment: What happens when you print "ws"?

Comment: Just for clarity; The active sheet the Sheet that has the focus when it comes to executing an action at the current point in time. It contains the 'active cell', ie the cell that the action will be performed on. There is only one active cell and sheet per workbook at any time so **wb.active** is never used to select a sheet by name or number but only to select this active sheet. Its use is only ever **var = <Workbook()>.active**. Putting the [1] at the end changed the variable 'ws' to a tuple representing a cell.

Comment: Selecting a sheet other than the active would usually be done by name; **ws = wb['Sheet2']** You can use index number if you happen to know what the index is; **wb.worksheets[1]**. [1] is not necessarily going to be the worksheet named 'Sheet2'.

Comment: Thanks moken! Makes sense and I could debug it :)

Comment: `ws = wb.active[1]` is the first row of whichever worksheet is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line `ws = wb.active[1]` is probably wrong. Also you should use `read_only=False` (simply remove this param, the default is `False`) if you want to modify the file.

You can assign ws by name. If you don't know the names you can list them like this:

```
>>> wb.sheetnames
['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3']
>>> ws = wb['Sheet2'] # or ws = wb.active - "Get the currently active sheet"
>>> ws["B3"] = "Germany"
```

Whole code:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl import load_workbook


# 1. Open Excel File
wb = Workbook()
wb = load_workbook(filename="myFile.xlsm", keep_vba=True, data_only=True)
ws = wb.active # the currently active sheet

# 2. Enter Input (Country)

ws["B3"] = "Germany"

wb.save("myFile.xlsm")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) This was indeed the Problem I missed.